Google Sheets - Find the first negative value in a row and return its row header
my Google Sheets file and the error I'm getting
The expected answer in this case is March 2010
I've tried using the formula available on other questions but it didn't work for me (maybe the formula works for columns but not rows)- need an expert's advice :)
Thanks!

Just do =INDEX(A1:F1,MATCH(TRUE,A2:F2<0)) , if you get a weird number, format your cell to a date.

Thanks @Excellor - tried that but its giving inaccurat result.
I'm getting 'June 2010' as output instead of the expected value -'March 2010'
Regarding cell format, I tried with plain strings as well (like June / May etc) but the output was still incorrect

=INDEX(A1:F1, MATCH(TRUE, A2:F2<0 , 0)) seems to fix it.

One of the main differences of Excel and GoogleSheet that the latter not use implicit array functions. You need to declare explicitly always.
Based on this the formula:
=INDEX(A1:F1,,ARRAYFORMULA(MATCH(true,A2:F2<0,0)))

Try this I've tested and it should work for you.
=xlookup(INDEX(A2:F2, MATCH(TRUE, A2:F2 < 0, 0)),A2:F2,A1:F1,"No Negative Number Found")

Using Index Match to return a header.
Try this:
=INDEX(A1:F1, MATCH(TRUE, A2:F2 < 0, 0))
Sample Output:

Reference:
INDEX
